# How to use ActiveModel::Serializers recursively outside of controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

The goal: serialize records recursively beyond one level of nesting outside of a Rails controller, where each nested record uses its own serializer.

I can successfully use ActiveModel::Serializers recursively from within a controller:

```
render json: @record, include: ['**']
```

And I can successfully use ActiveModel::Serializers outside of a controller to the first level of nesting:

```
RecordSerializer.new(@record, include: ['**']).as_json
```

However, the second piece of code does not recurse beyond the first level.

For example, let's say the first piece of code returns the following:

```
{
  "name": "Parent",
  "child": {
    "name": "Child",
    "grandchild": {
      "name": "Grandchild"
    }
  }
}
```

The second piece of code then returns the following:

```
{
  "name": "Parent",
  "child": {
    "name": "Child"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out.

You have to do this:

```
ActiveModelSerializers::SerializableResource
  .new(@record, include: ['**']).as_json
```

You can't call new on the serializer and pass it options; you have to use `ActiveModelSerializers::SerializableResource`.